# Merge two rows in table - identical data, expect one null field

Tags: sql, merge

I'm new in SQL, and have been wondering how i am able to join two rows, that are almost identical, expect for one field.

Here is a mockup of my table.

```
MODELNAME | PC Score | Rated Score | Prod Score | Temp  |  Temp1 | Temp2
Machine1  |  1234    |   2345      |  9000      |  NULL |  NULL  | NULL
Machine1  |   NULL   |   2345      |  9000      |  2356 |  2135  |  9123
```

So basically im just wondering how to merge those two together.

The first 4 fields will always be the same, but the second entry will be missing the "PC Score".. And after the 4 column - all the values on the first row will then be NULL...

Is it possible?

Answer (score 1):

You can use aggregation:

```
select modelname, max(pc_score) as pc_score, max(rated_score) as rated_score,
       max(prod_score) as prod_score,
       max(temp) as temp, max(temp1) as temp1, max(temp2) as temp2
from t
group by modelname;
```

That said, this problem usually arises when you have an aggregation query that does not have the right aggregation logic.  The better approach is to fix that query.  If this describes your situation, ask *another* question and include (a perhaps simplified version of) the query you are using.